# Utility that can add files to a volumed archive?

Tags: windows, archiving

Is there a utility/archive format that works on windows, that can add files to an already existing archive that is split into volumes (like file.rar.001, file.rar.002)? And if the size of these new files will be large enough, new volumes will be created automatically with the same maximum size that the existing volumes already have?

I have been trying with winrar, 7zip, they don't seem to be able to do this.